# Powermock Mockito : the method I'm trying to stubb ends up being called

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit4, mockito, powermock

I'm trying to test a `class A` which in turn autowires a `class B` :

```
public class A {

   @Autowired
   private B b;

   public int foo(int x, int y) {
       int z = b.bar(x, y, false);
       //do something with z
       return z;
   }
}
```

I'm using junit together with `powermock` and `mockito` to try to test the method `foo` in `class A`.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest(A.class)
public class TestA {

     @Test
     private void testFoo() {
        B b = PowerMockito.mock(B.class);
        when(b.bar(2,3,false)).thenReturn(5);
        A a = PowerMockito.spy(new A());
        Whitebox.setInternalState(a, "b", b);

        int z = a.foo(2,3);
        Assert.assertEquals(10,z);
     }

}
```

When i try to run the test I get a `NullPointerException` from within `class B`.
After using the debugger, I found out that right after stubbing the `bar` method of the `B class`, the `bar` method gets called.
The null pointer exception in this case is normal because the B class is not properly initialized.

Can anyone explain why this is happening and what can I do about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not a PowerMockito user, but don't you need to use `@PrepareForTest(B.class)`?  I think that annotation is for the class(es) you are mocking which is final or has statics, not for the class under test.

Also, why are you using `spy()` on A?  Perhaps your example code doesn't expose it, but I don't see the use.  And besides, do you really need `PowerMockito.spy()` for A, or would simply using Mockito's spy() be sufficient (i.e., are *both* A & B final and/or have statics that you need to access/mock/verify)?

Can I ask why you are using PowerMockito at all instead of just Mockito?  If it was merely to set the private B inside of A with `Whitebox`, you can do that with Mockito alone.  You just declare your A and B outside of the test method as:

```
@InjectMocks A a = new A();
@Mock B b;
```

and it will inject all @Mock mocks (i.e., `b`) into A.

PowerMock is mostly useful for cases where you are mocking static methods or final classes/methods.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Kevin. You are right about the `@PrepareForTest(B.class)`. I'm using spy() on A because I need another method of `class A` to be called when executing the test. And your right again, `Mockito.spy()` is sufficient. But none of these corrections solved my problem.

Comment: are you trying to do an explicit Mockito `verify(...)` on the other method of A, not shown in your example?  If not, then just create a real instance of A, let Mockito inject the mocked B (as shown in edited answer), and then the call to the first method of A will call the other method in A with no problem.

Comment: I'm using PowerMock instead of Mockito because I have other test methods in this test class that need to mock static fields. Yes, I'm using an explicit verify() in order to verify that a method is being called and to capture it's arguments.

Comment: that's fine, but if you are not using statics in this test, then just use the plain Mockito.mock() for this case.  Or better yet, use `@InjectMocks` and `@Mock`.

Comment: Our replies are overlapping :-)  Anyway, don't eliminate PowerMock from your test class (since you can't), but only use its facilities where required.  Generally you shouldn't use spies unless you have a really heinous legacy class. Otherwise a unit test should test the class as a unit. Invoking method 1 -- even if it invokes method 2 -- should have an observable change in the state of the class A and/or predictable interactions with collaborators.  Spy-ing so that you can verify method 2, so that you can capture and verify arguments to method 2 is taking whitebox testing a bit too far.

Comment: The issue was in fact with the **@PrepareForTest** annotation. When I used `@PrepareForTest(B.class)` it worked fine.